# Add filter to FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net, templates

How to add filter to the fileupload control in asp.net? I want a filter for Word Template File (.dot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do a javascript alternative to filtering it server side (you'd probably want to do that as well) but this saves the client from spending the time waiting on an upload to finish just to find out it was the wrong type.

http://javascript.internet.com/forms/upload-filter.html

So basically you just run a javascript function on submit that parses off the extension of the uploaded file and gives them an alert if its not of the right type.

You could also use document.forms[0].submit(); instead of passing the form reference through (as ASP.NET really only uses a single form (unless your doing something funky))

Answer (score 2):

```
        string fileName = fuFiles.FileName;

        if(fileName.Contains(".dot"))
        {
            fuFiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to filter the file extensions client/side, with the standard browser's file selector, isn't possible.
To do that you have to use a mixed type of upload, such as [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/), based on a flash uploader system (that's a really nice techinque: it allows you to post more than a file at time).

The only thing you can do in standard mode is to filter the already posted file, and I suggest to use System.IO.Path namespace utility:

```
if (Path.GetExtension(upFile.FileName).ToUpper().CompareTo(".DOT") == 0) 
{
    /* do what you want with file here */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the filename of the uploaded file serverside:

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
```

Unless you want to use java or something similar on the client, there's really not much you can do for filtering uploaded files before they're sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have a small method that I used to filter which types of files can be uploaded by the fileupload control named fuLogo.

```
if (fuLogo.HasFile)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string[] fileBreak = fuLogo.FileName.Split(new char[] { '.' });
            logo = Server.MapPath("../Images/Logos/" + fileBreak[0] + counter.ToString()+ "." + fileBreak[1]);
            if (fileBreak[1].ToUpper() == "GIF" || fileBreak[1].ToUpper() == "PNG")
            {
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(logo))
                {
                    counter++;
                    logo = Server.MapPath("../Images/Logos/" + fileBreak[0] + counter.ToString() + "." + fileBreak[1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cvValidation.ErrorMessage = "This site does not support any other image format than .Png or .Gif . Please save your image in one of these file formats then try again.";
                cvValidation.IsValid = false;
            }
            fuLogo.SaveAs(logo);
        }
```

basically, I first Iterates through the directory to see if a file already exists. Should the file exist, (example picture0.gif) , it will increase the counter (to picture1.gif).  It prevents that different users will overwrite each other's pictures should their pictures have the same name.

Comment: this will fail if your filename is myFile.1.png, use Path.GetExtension(theFileName) instead